# What is compressing responses in express and why is it important?

Tags: node.js, express

I was going through [this code (linnovate mean boilerplate code)](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) and I have seen [they have used a package](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/server/config/express.js#L49) called [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) as a middleware.

In [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) compression is described as:

> ... The middleware will attempt to compress response bodies for all
>   request that traverse through the middleware, based on the given
>   options.

1. What exactly is compressing the response body? Is it making it smaller and wouldn't this change the data?
2. Why is it important? Why not just send the response body uncompressed?

**-----EDIT-----**

3. And how is it decompressed by the client is there a package that does that? How does it work?

Comment: Why is compression used ever? Do you want to download 1GB or 100MB instead?

Comment: There's and entire Wikipedia article about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I guess sometimes you need someone to remind you the obvious  :)@Slebetman Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make the website more responsive, compressing data reduces the overall size of response hence faster loading times.

Compressed data is decompressed on the client side, so the data remains same.

Browser is responsible for decompressing the response automatically which is compressed and sent by server. Only thing required from client is to send an header containing decompression techniques supported.

```
Accept-encoding: gzip
```

So when browser sends the above header, server can send compressed response using *gzip* and browser will automatically decompress the response.

Comment: What package in this case [(the code referenced in the question)](https://github.com/linnovate/mean), is used to decompress on the client side or does it happen automatically?

Comment: Updated the answer